# Error 500 When return View from controller during ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

i have to create ajax call when user clicks on checkboxes to fetch the specific jobs  according to each checkbox category . 
When in controller i return `return \Response::json($jobs)` The request works fine . But when im trying to return `return View::make('jobs.alljobs')->with('jobs', $jobs);` i got Error 500

**JobController.php**

```
$cat = Input::get('categories');
    $jobs = Job::whereIn('category_id',$cat)->get();
    return View::make('jobs.alljobs')->with('jobs', $jobs);
```

**AJAX Call function**

```
function filterCategories(){

//Mark : Categories filters jquery
var categories = [];
// Listen for 'change' event
$('input[name="cat[]"]').on('change', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  categories = []; // reset 
  $('input[name="cat[]"]:checked').each(function()
  {
      categories.push($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(categories);
  //Send request
$.ajax({
    url: '/jobs/searchcat',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {categories:categories},
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content'));
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
})});}
```

[Result when i return json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va8PF.png)

[Error when i return view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsAkJ.png)

Comment: But why you are trying to return a view? the ajax call is excepting a JSON data to be displayed or manipulated not an HTML file or PHP file or the template engine that you are using, and 500 internal servers it does mean that there is an error in your back-end code, just check server log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably means that your script is throwing an uncaught error or exception when you return the view. Enable error logging and check your logs. Either of these pages might help with that.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging

Comment: Indeed the problem was my view .I thought was request or csrf problem.... Thanks so much .